# convert set of numbers to date in angular 10

Tags: angular, date, datetime

I have a string that has this format

> 20220125

> yyyymmdd

But I need to convert this to the below format

> 2021-01-25

Is there way to do it with angular 10?

Comment: "Moment" NPM package probably the easiest. https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: have you tried the Date Pipe? https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a valid ISO date it should be formatted as: '2022-01-25'. Here is an example for you which could be of course made more reliable. But for demonstration purpouses it should work.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dateVal: Date;
  dateString = '20220125'
  constructor() {
    this.convertStringToDate(this.dateString)
  }

  convertStringToDate(dateString: string) {
    if (dateString.length == 8) {
      let formatedString = dateString.slice(0, 4) + '-' + dateString.slice(4, 6) + '-' + dateString.slice(6, 8);
      const dateObj = new Date(formatedString);
      console.log(formatedString);
      console.log(dateObj);
      this.dateVal = dateObj;

    }
  }
}
```

`2022-01-25`

`2022-01-25T00:00:00.000Z`

Here is a working demo for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/date-pipe-example-k4zewb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use straight-up Javascript and replace the string using a regex pattern.

```
const date = "20220125";
const re = date.replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3");
console.log(re)

> "2022-01-25"
```